# How to add "eosio.code" permission to an account on testnet?

Tags: cleos, permissions, testnet, error

I am trying to add a the "eosio.code" permission to an account on testnet. I am using the following command:

```
cleos -u https://api.testnet.eos.io set account permission lsqkeotnnpyu active '{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"permission":{"key":"EOS57G...Ua9","permission":"active"},"weight":1}],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"lsqkeotnnpyu","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p lsqkeotnnpyu@active
```

However I get the following error:

> Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
>   Error Details:
>   assertion failure with message: key which is used during account creation (can be checked in eosio:eosio:accountkeys table) must not be removed

I couldn't find a way to fix the error so far, thanks for the help.

Comment: thanks so much for this question and the subsequent answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is specific to the EOSIO testnet from Block One. You can try adding it by doing the following:

`cleos -u https://api.testnet.eos.io set account permission lsqkeotnnpyu active --add-code`

Let us know if this solution works for you

Comment: thank you so much for this, this was an answer Ive been looking for for hours.